# How to get F-Droid to detect updates of itself - how to remove "ignored updates"?

Tags: f-droid

I'm using F-Droid and noticed that there are newer versions of the F-Droid app available that are not shown when F-Droid checks for updates.

I found that when looking at F-Droid's options > installed applications that F-Droid is listed there, but with a note "ignored updates" (maybe the wording is different, I'm using a translation).

On the App page, there is no "update" button, but just "start".

Is there a way to indicate that F-Droid also looks for updates of itself?

F-Droid came pre-installed with my Shift phone, so maybe, that's the reason why there is this setting.

Comment: Have you tried the settings from within F-Droid? From the "hamburger" menu (the three dots) in the header when F-Droid is started, do you have "Ignore All Updates" unchecked?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't check the options there, only the general options. Ok, now I feel kind of stupid ... If you write an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F-Droid App controls its own updating through an option within the app. When you start F-Droid, visit the internal settings in the "hamburger" menu ( the three dots). It can have its own updates restricted if the setting "Ignore All Updates" is checked. Uncheck this setting to allow F-Droid to maintain itself.